# Navbar-fixed-top no es responsivo, y no muestra por completo lo que viene abajo

Tags: css, bootstrap

Para comenzar les quiero comentar que al momento de hacer este navegador superior no tenía en consideración que esto ocurriría, lo creé en base a clases de boostrap pero no salió como yo quería, a continuación les presento el problema.

Tengo un `nav` el cual no es responsivo, esto implica que cuando veo en pantallas muy pequeñas la página el menú superior desaparece, también lo que venga bajo el menú superior se vera tras él ya que es `fixed`, les mostraré con imágenes.

**Menu superior en pantallas de pc**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Menu superior en pantallas pequeñas(celular)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Menu superior ocultando lo que aparece atras**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código del menu superior con clases bootstrap**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GetJob</a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- <li class="active"> <a href="#">Menu Principal</a> </li> -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="eventos/" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Eventos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu text-center" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item " href="eventos/crear">Crear Evento</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="eventos/visualizar">Ver Eventos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="eventos/misEventos">Mis Eventos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="verperfil({{user.id_user}});">Perfil</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="logout">Cerrar Sesion
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Código de lo que viene bajo el menu superior:**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Evento:
                    {{d.nombre}}</h3>
                <h4 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Personal:
                    {{d.funcion}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text text-muted">Fecha:
                    {{d.fecha}}</p>
                {% if d.fecha >= fecha %}
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">TOMAR EMPLEO</a>
                    <a id="masInformacion" class="btn btn-success">MAS INFORMACIÓN</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">EMPLEO FINALIZADO</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema... ¿Quieres hacerlo responsive por completo o únicamente que la parte de la página que se oculta tras él se vea?

Comment: @Rabegi Aparte de verse la parte de atrás, hacerlo responsivo ya que el problema es que la pagina en su totalidad parte desde el margen 0 como el navbar esta fixed esto tapa los primeros pixeles y no se logra distinguir bien

Comment: Técnicamente sí que es responsive, al llegar a x tamaño los links que has marcado como `collapse` desaparecen, te falta que aparezca el menú hamburguesa para marcar que existen más cosas. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp  <-- Prueba con el último ejemplo

Comment: @Rabegi gracias estoy probando ojala resulte!